# Переадресация ссылки с пробелом через .htaccess. Как?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые участники.

Имеется ссылка вида `https://domen.com/category/news-odin-dla-posetitelej.html`
Дело в том, что её разместили криво на одном ресурсе и люди переходящие в итоге открывают `https://domen.com/category/news-odin-dla-posetitelej.html ,`
Имеется пробел и запятая и соответственно открывается 404 страница.
Как мне с использованием .htaccess сделать так, чтобы в итоге их переадресовывало на нужную страницу?

Пробовал так:

```
Redirect 301 "/category/news-odin-dla-posetitelej.html ," https://domen.com/category/news-odin-dla-posetitelej.html
```

И вот так

```
Redirect 301 /category/news-odin-dla-posetitelej.html[\s], https://domen.com/category/news-odin-dla-posetitelej.html
```

Но, к сожалению, не помогает.

Может поступить основательно и отсекать сам пробел и всё что после него? Если это резонно, то напишите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать через .htaccess.

P.S. 
Платформа Wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте проще

```
RewriteEngine On
# если за нужным url еще есть символы (тут, отличные от слэша)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/category/news\-odin\-dla\-posetitelej\.html[^/]+
# то делаем 301 редирект на нужный url
RewriteRule . https://domen.com/category/news-odin-dla-posetitelej.html [R=301,QSA,L]
```

P.S. Редирект предлагаю ставить первым в .htaccess, перед всеми другими правилами переадресации.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Этот вариант отлично сработал :-)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы добавить пробел, нужно его экранировать слешем `\`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)
RewriteRule ^category\/news\-odin\-dla\-posetitelej\.html\ \,$ https://domen.com/category/news-odin-dla-posetitelej.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Предложенный вариант не работает :-(